# How to select all rows in a large text file that contain a specific text string

Tags: linux, excel, bash, awk

I have a multicolumn text file (23 columns, ~ 450,000 rows) from which I would like to extracts only those rows that contain the word "plant" in column 9 (for example). Ideally I would like to create a sub_file that contains the data for "plants" only so that I can manipulate it with excel (the original file won't load completely on excel). I have used awk in the past for some table parsing chores but I can't make this work. I have used the following awk command unsuccessfully:

```
$ awk '$9="plant"' file_in.txt > file_out.txt
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Just do `$9 == "plant"` instead of `=` (double `=`). The rest is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to extracts only those rows that **contain** the word "plant" in column 9

if this is the requirement, I guess you would do:

```
awk '$9~/plant/' file_in.txt > file_out.txt
```

if you want to get rows with col9 **equals** "plant":

```
awk '$9=="plant"' file_in.txt > file_out.txt
```

btw, I don't know if there is another question @SO tagged with `linux`, `awk` and `Excel` !!  Funny..

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - Thank you. I suppose that a "script" to do all the parsing tasks that I wish to do is better but I'll settle for a few "one-liners."